# How to FX.Accordion on mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, accordion, behavior-ui

I am creating a checkout page design that has an accordion. My employer only allows mootools as their js framework and doesn't want jquery on their application. I am using BehaviorUI for front-end framework as it is a replica of bootstrap but are built based on mootools. The only problem is I am having trouble on creating the next/continue button for the next accordion.

here is what I have tried so far but turns out no luck:

```
<div class="panel-group checkout-accordion" id="accordion" data-behavior="Accordion" data-accordion-options="'headers': 'a.accordion-toggle', 'sections': '.panel-collapse'">        
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle"><span class="badge pull-left custom-badge">1</span>
                   <h3 class="panel-title"> Checkout Method </h3>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="step1" class="panel-collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>You're Logged in as Erica!</h3>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-trigger="reveal" data-reveal-target="!.panel-group .panel #step2">Continue <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default" id="test">
            <div class="panel-heading">                    
                <a class="accordion-toggle"><span class="badge pull-left custom-badge">2</span>
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Shipping Method</h3>
                </a>                    
            </div>
            <div id="step2" class="panel-collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Destination State And Zip Code</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="state" class="control-label">State</label>
                        <select id="state" class="no-flat-select form-control">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Select State</option>
                            <option value="1">Florida</option>
                            <option value="2">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="3">Alaska</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="zip" class="control-label">Zip Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Continue <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

As further explanation of what my goal is. Here is an image that might help - [link to image](http://ft3.dtupload.com/0o/accordion.png)

Comment: Can you explain in this jsFiddle what is working wrong? --> http://jsfiddle.net/smgop433/ Please adapt it to show your problem so we can help you.

Comment: @Sergio The problem I have encountered is the anchortag / continue button does not work at all. and does not even throw an error.. I have updated my post please try to see the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to just go look at what Behavior.Accordion.js is doing ([source here on github](https://github.com/Behavior-UI/behavior-ui/blob/master/js/Source/Accordion/Behavior.Fx.Accordion.js))

All it does is create an instance of `Fx.Accordion` for you. Your use of the `reveal` delegator is sort of out of scope of the accordion in that it, independently, knows how to show things, but it doesn't invoke any of `Fx.Accordion`'s methods (which wouldn't hide the first section).

No problem though. Just write a new delegator!

http://jsfiddle.net/4y5sLt5d/

```
Delegator.register('click', {
  'showAccordionSection': {
    requireAs: {
      // gotta tell it which section you want to show
      target: String
    },
    defaults: {
      // how to find the accordion instance
      // by convention, all selectors are relative to the element with
      // the trigger. this default assumes the clicked element is inside
      // the accordion.
      accordionSelector: '![data-behavior*=Accordion]'
    },
    handler: function(event, element, api){
      // find the target section to show
      var target = api.getElement('target');
      // we gotta find the accordion instance, so we look for
      var accordionElement = api.getElement('accordionSelector');
      // get the accordion instance from the element, created by Behavior
      var accordionInstance = accordionElement.getBehaviorResult('Accordion');
      // no accordion found? fail quietly
      if (!accordionInstance) api.fail('Could not retrieve Fx.Accordion instance from element', accordionElement);
      // not a section of the accordion? fail quietly
      if (accordionInstance.elements.indexOf(target) < 0) api.fail('Target element is not an accordion section', target);
      // show it!
      accordionInstance.display(target);
    }
  }
});
```

Just drop that anywhere into your site's javascript (after `Delegator` of course) and you're good to go.